# Como comparar un jtextfiel con un string

Tags: eclipse, java-swing

Debo comparar un dato ingresado por el `jtextfiel` con el dato que esta un archivo `txt` y al momento de comparar me dice:

> Incompatible operand types string and JTextField

el dato que quiero comparar es el usuario y contraseña:

```
public int leerficheroo(){
String fichero = "C:/Usuario.txt";
try {
  FileReader fr = new FileReader(fichero);
  BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);

  String linea;
  while((linea = br.readLine()) != null) {
      String[] lineaArreglo = linea.split(";");
      String usuario=lineaArreglo[1];
      String contrasena=lineaArreglo[2];

      if(usuario.equals(ventana1.user) && contrasena.equals(ventana1.pass)) 
      {
          return 1;
      }
      else
          return 2;

  }
```

el error me sale en el (if) al preguntar si el dato del txt es igual al del jtextfiel que esta en otra clase en la cual trate de cambiar el tipo de dato asi

```
public static JTextField txtUsuario;
public static JPasswordField passUsuario;
static String user = txtUsuario.getText();
static String pass = passUsuario.getText();
```

Comment: Prueba `ventana1.user.getText()`

Comment: que tipo de datos estas dejando ingresar en el password?

Comment: quiero utilizarlos como string todos

Answer (score 0):

Con tu porcion de codigo he tratado de armar el mismo workbenck, solo que los datos de usuario y contrasena los tomo de la misma clase.

Considera:

1. `String usuario=lineaArreglo[1];
    String contrasena=lineaArreglo[2];`

   te va a dar un

   > ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

ya que el arreglo comienza en la posicion '0'

2. La funcion `leerFicheroo()` va a tener que devolver algun valor por defecto.
3. Con respecto a la clase ventana fijate de tener inicializado el objeto y los valores de usuario y contresena.

Saludos.

**Nota**: Si queres subir el resto de las clases podria verlo con mejor detalle.

Answer (score 0):

Suponiendo que user y pass sean los jTextField con los que quieres comparar, solo te faltó agregarle el getText().
En lugar de esto:

`if(usuario.equals(ventana1.user) && contrasena.equals(ventana1.pass))`

Utiliza esto:

`if(usuario.equals(ventana1.user.getText()) && contrasena.equals(ventana1.pass.getText()))`

Espero ser de ayuda, saludos!